# Why don't we say a blessing before giving charity?

Tags: halacha, blessing, mitzvah, tzedakah-charity

Before doing many *mitzvos* (commandments), we are required *derabanan* to say a blessing. Why is this not the same for giving *tzedakah* (charity)?

Comment: I believe this has been asked before

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Shalom and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @sam I would have thought so as well but couldn't find it through tags or a direct search

Comment: @sam See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/34977/128, but it's not the same question.

Comment: @sam I was thinking of the question yydl linked to, but there’s a lot of overlap with the answers to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17730/ as well. Still not a dupe.

Comment: Your question made the Hot Network Question list (and therefore will get exposure to many non-Jews) so I translated bits to make it easier for them to understand. Congrats on achieving this with your first-ever question on the site!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Great question. A writer from the Houston Community Kollel has surveyed historical answers to this famous question ([here](https://www.torchweb.org/torah_detail.php?id=476))

> (1) The great medieval commentator **Rashba** (1235-1310) in his
>   Responsa (1:18) offers the following rule: **Any mitzvah which is not
>   entirely in the hands of the one performing it, as it requires the
>   participation of another person for its fulfilment**, e.g. the mitzvah
>   of tzedakah which requires that a poor person accept the charity for
>   the mitzvah to be fulfilled, no blessing is recited before performing
>   it. [The logic behind this rule could be that if the giver recites a
>   blessing and then the poor person refuses to take the tzedakah, the
>   giver will have uttered a blessing and G-ds Name in vain.] BTW, this
>   rule also explains why no blessing is recited before the mitzvos of
>   Honoring Ones Parents, Visiting the Sick, and Returning a Lost Object.
>
> (2) **Rabbi Elazar of Worms** (c. 1176-1238), writes in his Sefer
>   HaRokeach (ch. 366) that the Sages did not ordain a blessing before
>   any mitzvah like tzedakah, **which is based on logic and common sense
>   and is therefore performed by non-Jews as well**. The reason for this
>   rule is because the entire purpose of our doing mitzvos is to sanctify
>   ourselves and to help us lead more elevated and spiritual lives than
>   those around us - as we say in the standard form of blessing before
>   performing a mitzvah: Who has sanctified us with His commandments.
>   However, when performing a mitzvah that is also performed by non-Jews,
>   as in the case of tzedakah, our sanctification as Jews is not readily
>   evident and thus no blessing is recited.
>
> (3) The **Avudraham** writes that the Sages **did not ordain a
>   blessing before the performance of a mitzvah which involves another
>   persons pain**. A poor person often feels pained and embarrassed to
>   have to receive tzedakah, and it is improper and inappropriate to
>   recite a blessing at another person's misfortune.
>
> (4) The **Maharsham** (1835-1911) in his Halachic commentary Daas
>   Torah (YD #61) writes that we don't make a blessing before performing
>   the mitzvah of tzedakah **because it's really not our money to give
>   away**. We are just agents of G-d who are holding the money that G-d
>   gave us for safekeeping until a poor person comes along and G-d
>   commands us to give it to him. As King David is quoted as saying in I
>   Chronicles 29:14: "For everything is from You, and from Your hand have
>   we given it to you". We thus don't recite a blessing on the act of
>   giving tzedakah since G-d is really doing all the work, not us.
>
> (5) Other commentators suggest a more practical reason why the Sages
>   did not ordain a blessing to be recited before giving tzedakah to a
>   poor person. They were worried that **the poor person to whom we give
>   tzedakah might be a cheater and not as poor as we think**, and then no
>   mitzvah will have been fulfilled and the blessing will have been made
>   in vain. Unfortunately, the Jewish people have had a long history of
>   cheaters living among us who masquerade as poor people but in reality
>   are quite wealthy. As Rabbi Elazar is quoted in the Talmud as saying
>   well over 1500 years ago (see Kesubos 67b-68a), Come let us be
>   grateful to the cheaters, for were it not for them we [who do not
>   always respond to every appeal for tzedakah] would be considered
>   sinners every day [but due to the many cheaters out there we are off
>   the hook somewhat].